# SwiftUI - Getting Path to redraw after variables updated

Tags: swiftui, view, path, shapes

I have a TextField that dictates the angle of a solar panel, the default is 10 degrees.

[image]

If I alter this to 80 the variables update as shown below:

[image]

What doesn't happen is that the Path drawing the panels doesn't get refreshed. The text clearly does.

displayPanelSpacing is called which in turn calls drawPanels. From the print statement in drawPanels I know that it is receiving the correct, updated numbers.

The grey lines only seem to be generating when the view loads for the first time. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct displayPanelSpacing: View{
    @ObservedObject var variables: Variables
    @State private var changeLine = false
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 20.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Panel Spacing " + String(variables.tiltAngle) + "°")
            
            drawPanels(variables: variables)
                .stroke(changeLine ? Color(.red) : .gray, lineWidth: 3.0)
                .frame(width: (GlobalVariables.screenWidth - 64), height: 150)
                .padding(.leading, 16)
                .padding(.trailing, 16)
                .scaleEffect(changeLine ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                .overlay(DrawSun(radius: 25).foregroundColor(.orange))
            // .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1.0), value: offset)
        }
    }
}

struct drawPanels: Shape {
    @ObservedObject var variables: Variables

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let result = variables.ed()
        let edEndX = result.endX
        let edEndY = result.endY

        let baselineY = rect.maxY - 0
        let baselineXOffset = 10
        let panelY = Int(rect.maxY) - edEndY
        let panel1X = baselineXOffset + edEndX
        let panel2X = baselineXOffset + Int(rect.midX) + edEndX
        
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 10, y: baselineY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: panel1X, y: panelY))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + 10, y: baselineY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: panel2X, y: panelY))
        let _ = print("Received", String(edEndY), String(panelY))
        return path
    }
}
```

The input TextField is:

```
struct PanelSpacingView: View {
    @StateObject var variables: Variables = Variables()
    ...
    var body: some View {
    ...
      HStack {
         Text("Tilt Angle")
              .padding(.leading, 16)
         TextField("Tilt Angle", value: $variables.tiltAngle, formatter: formatter)
              .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
              .disableAutocorrection(true)
              .padding(.leading, 16)
              .padding(.trailing, 16)                          
         Text("°")
               .padding(.trailing, 16)
       }
```

Comment: Where is your `TextField`, how do you use it to update the `variables`. How and where do you declare the required `@StateObject var variables = Variables()`. How do you pass it to the other views? Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Without testing, I wouldn't be confident that an `ObservedObject` works inside a `Shape`. I'd pass the `variables.ed()` result to the `Shape` explicitly in a parameter. Agree with above that this needs a [mre]

Comment: Apologies - TextField code added. From the print statement I know the figures are being updated and correct, so the variables are being passed . The issue is that the path isn't being redrawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `Shape` protocol includes `View` it seems it does not
work with the `@ObservedObject var variables: Variables` in the `DrawPanels`.

So I suggest you use a simpler approach, using a `@Binding` in `DrawPanels` as shown in the example code.

Without a complete workable code, all I can do, is propose an approach that should work.
Adjust the code to your specific needs.

```
struct DisplayPanelSpacing: View {
    @ObservedObject var variables: Variables
    @State private var changeLine = false
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 20.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Panel Spacing " + String(variables.tiltAngle) + "°")
            
            DrawPanels(angle: $variables.tiltAngle)  // <-- here, pass whatever is needed
                .stroke(changeLine ? .red : .gray, lineWidth: 3.0)
                .frame(width: (GlobalVariables.screenWidth - 64), height: 150)
                .padding(.leading, 16)
                .padding(.trailing, 16)
                .scaleEffect(changeLine ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                .overlay(DrawSun(radius: 25).foregroundColor(.orange))
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1.0), value: offset)
        }
    }
}

struct DrawPanels: Shape {
    @Binding var angle: Int  // <-- here
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let result = Result(endX: angle, endY: 33)  // <-- here, whatever the equivalent of `variables.ed()`
        let edEndX = result.endX
        let edEndY = result.endY
        
        let baselineY = rect.maxY - 0
        let baselineXOffset = 10
        let panelY = Int(rect.maxY) - edEndY
        let panel1X = baselineXOffset + edEndX
        let panel2X = baselineXOffset + Int(rect.midX) + edEndX
        
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + 10, y: baselineY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: panel1X, y: panelY))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + 10, y: baselineY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: panel2X, y: panelY))
        return path
    }
}

// for testing
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var variables: Variables = Variables()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Tilt Angle").padding(.leading, 16)
                TextField("Tilt Angle", value: $variables.tiltAngle, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .padding(.leading, 16)
                    .padding(.trailing, 16)
                Text("°").padding(.trailing, 16)
            }
            DisplayPanelSpacing(variables: variables)
        }
    }
    
}

// for testing
class Variables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tiltAngle = 10
}
// for testing
struct Result {
    var endX: Int
    var endY: Int
}
```

Comment: Genius - that approach works. What I don't understand is that both methods pass the correct values drawPanels but the ObservedObject does not trigger the image to be redrawn: the @Binding does. Many thanks.